# What sort of functions can be used with mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

Can any user function be used with `dplyr`'s `mutate`, or is it only a limited set of functions? If the former, what requirements exactly must the function meet? If the latter, where is the full list of these functions?

From the [data wrangling cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf), I know some basic functions that can be used with mutate such as `lead` and `lag`. I also know that arithmetic operations like `mutate(df, sum = a+b)` work. The cheat sheet mentions that it "uses window functions" - what does this mean? Is window function the same as [described in `stats`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.2/topics/window)? What does subsetting have to do with combining a bunch of variables?

Comment: The cheat sheet gives the definition of "window functions" - *"Mutate uses 
window functions, functions that take a vector of values and return another vector of values"*. You can use any user-written function you want, you just have to make sure it returns a vector (usually the same length as the input vectors).

Comment: @Marius That's not really a useful definition, since it doesn't explain what R type is meant by *vector*.

Comment: How is "vector" ambiguous in R? A vector is zero or more values of the same class/type, often formed by wrapping with `c(...)`. (I say "zero" because technically `character(0)` is still a vector of length 0.)

Comment: Informally, *vector* here means "a vector that can be used as a dataframe/tibble column", which should cover most vectors.

Comment: In R, almost every object is [a vector](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html). Colloquially, people tend to only refer to [atomic vectors](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#atomic-vectors) as vectors, but [lists are vectors too](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#lists), which means [data frames](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#tibble) and most models and so on are all vectors. In this context, what's more important than type or class is the length, which must match up with the number of rows in the data frame.